# Actions: Change Order Not available, sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, list

I'm attempting to re-order the steps in a custom list. For some reason I am not able to go to "Actions" and hit "Change Order" as I'm able to do in other lists.

I've tried editing the view preferences, but in my view I can't find the "allow users to order items in this view" option. Is it possible to change the order of items in custom lists in 2007? We have many other lists on this site and this seems to be one of the few that I can't re-arrange.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are describing is only applicable in Links lists.

Comment: I have a backlog of list templates left by a previous employee but I'm not sure which one is the one that is being used on the website as standard procedure. Is there a way to look at an existing list and see what template was used to create it?

Comment: The easiest method is to go to View All Site Content and look at the icon associated with the list. If it is a globe with a link/infinity type symbol, it's based on a links list.